# What is the point of setting variables to True or False?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

I am watching a tutorial video on Youtube about Python basics.
During the video he creates a lists and writes a code to print out "Found" if there are any words beginning with the letter "J". 
[image: screenshot of code] 
Here is the code:

```
names = ["John", "Mary"]
found = False
for name in names:
    if name.startswith("J"):
        print("Found")
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("Not found")
```

My question is why he decided to set the variable `found` to `False` at the beginning of the code if he then changes it to `True` towards the bottom?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you omit the setting to false and none of the names in `names` start with J?

Comment: The `found` variable is only set to true inside an `if` statement. At the end of the program, the checking if the variable is true or false will tell you if that if-condition was ever met.

Comment: Off-topic: FWIW, you often don't need to use "flag" variables like this at all in Python because [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) statements have an optional `else:` clause which can be use in scenarios like this (i.e. searching for something that may or may not be found). Maybe the tutorial is a little _too_ basic…

Comment: @DerekEden Why do you think that? I don’t feel that’s true **at all**. (Hi btw)

Comment: @Pitto I didnt even notice the down votes honestly.. Im just here to learn and get answers when I get stuck Lol But I agree with you.

Comment: @Pitto I agree but doesnt always happen

Comment: Then people like users partecipating in this question should be more present / active, @DerekEden :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it would be clearer if it were written like this:

```
names = ["John", "Mary"]
found = False
for name in names:
    if name.startswith("J"):
        found = True
        break

if found:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

This is functionally the same, but the role of `found` should be clearer.

---

Although as [@martineau commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230152/what-is-the-point-of-setting-variables-to-true-or-false/59231009#comment104674883_59230152), you don't even need `found` since Python has an `else` clause you can add to a `for` loop, which activates when the loop is unbroken:

```
names = ["John", "Mary"]
for name in names:
    if name.startswith("J"):
        print("Found")
        break
else:  # No break
    print("Not found")
```

Or here's another option using a generator expression and a ternary, based on [@Daniel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230152/what-is-the-point-of-setting-variables-to-true-or-false/59231009#comment104673846_59230193):

```
names = ["John", "Mary"]
found = any(name.startswith("J") for name in names)
print("Found" if found else "Not found")
```

Comment: Yes ok thank you! This way makes more since for me. I can understand now why he did it that way as well. But what was confusing me is whether or not 'found' continues to remain True if I continued on with more code, or if it resorts back to False once I leave the for loop. If this is the case would I have to set it True once again if I wanted to use it again later?

Comment: @Dcode In the snippet you posted, `found`'s value will never change after the loop. Does that answer your quesiton?

Comment: The else for the for loop is simply new to me!
Cool beans :)

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the code, we check the value of `found`. If we didn't trigger the `found = True` statement, then `found` will be `False`. Otherwise, it will be `True`. This allows us to figure out whether we found at least one name that starts with "J".

If we didn't set `found = False` at the beginning, we wouldn't be able to use `found` later - because the variable might not have been created by the time we reached the `if` statement that would have used it.

So, in other words, the value of `found` changes depending on what happens in the program, and we use that variable to keep track of that change.

Answer (score 1):

The use of this boolean variable is called "Flag" in programming:

> A flag variable, in its simplest form, is a variable you define to
>   have one value until some condition is true, in which case you change
>   the variable's value. It is a variable you can use to control the flow
>   of a function or statement, allowing you to check for certain
>   conditions while your function progresses.

The programmer sets the variable to False at the beginning of the code and the variable will change only if the name has been found.
The variable is used only to check, at the end of the code, if the last print must be executed or not.

At the end of the code, in case found is True then the print "Not found" will be executed.

Try to imagine a scenario where the name is not found...
What would be the variable value?
Will the last print be executed?

There's also another possibility to obtain the same result without the boolean variable using carefully the return in a function (you'll learn about functions later):

```
def find_name_in_names(name_first_letter, names):
    for name in names:
        if name.startswith(name_first_letter):
            return("Found")
    return("Not Found")

names = ["John", "Mary"]

print(find_name_in_names("J", names))
```

Comment: The function `find_name_in_names` should return `True` or `False`, not a string. `return` is no funktion, so parentheses are not needed, and should be removed. You can use `any`:  `return any(name.startswith(name_first_letter) for name in names)`.

Comment: Hi @Daniel! It was just an example to show how to obtain the optional print without the flag variable. Solution are countless, it was just a simple example. In case I had written a function to return a boolean probably I would've chosen a name similar to is_name_in_names.  
Thanks for your input!